# openx / revive website Statistics

Tags: openx

I am using revive. I am using in the banner js this code

```
document.write ("?zoneid=14&what=468x60&source=food");
```

that is return only banner that are in size 468x60 and with channel food. the limitation is working good.

in: revive ->  Statistics - > Websites & Zone

I need to get statistic base on the Websites that published in its site the banner.
the problem is that the statistic do not display the Websites statistic (I get just the Advertisers & Campaigns stats).

so I can not know in what site the banner display.

can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

OpenX called the invocation code based on "what=" **direct selection** (I assume, this is still true for revive-adserver. The problem is, with direct selection, the parameter zoneid will be ignored - instead, impression and clicks are logged into the database with zoneid=0. You may have a look in to the adservers database (usually MySQL), have a look at {prefix_}data_summary_ad_hourly.

I am sorry there is no workaround, maybe it is possible to write a plugin, to override the default behaviour, but I am not sure.